# Jest not mocking return value of library function correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jwt

I am trying to test a redux saga using jest.  Here's the saga:

```
// saga.ts

import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

export function* handleUserRetrieved(action): Generator {
  const { access_token, id_token } = action.payload;
  // Find token issue date and expiration date and add expiration event
  const decodedAccessToken = jwtDecode(access_token) as JWT;

  try {
    // make api call with some information from the JWT
    axios.get('/user/endpoint').then(...)
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle potential errors from api call
}
```

I don't want `jwtDecode` to actually run.  I want to mock the return value of that function in jest, so that I can continue to test the rest of the code in the function.  This code used to work:

```
// saga.test.ts

import SagaTester from "redux-saga-tester";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("jwt-decode");

jest.mock("redux-saga/effects", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("redux-saga/effects"),
  delay: jest.fn()
}));

const mockJwt = "jwt";

describe("Auth saga", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sagaTester = new SagaTester({ initialState });
    sagaTester.start(saga);
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("should handle getting user info from JWT", async () => {
    const mockAdapter = new MockAdapter(axios);

    // Here I want to ensure that the real jwtDecode doesn't run,
    // but rather the return value is mocked with the following:
    (jwtDecode as unknown as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
      resource_access: {
        myapp: {
          roles: mockRoles
        }
      }
    });

    mockAdapter.onGet("/user/endpoint").reply(200, mockPermissions);

    sagaTester.dispatch({
      type: USER_FOUND,
      payload: { access_token: mockJwt }
    });

    const successAction = await sagaTester.waitFor(
      "USER_CREATED_SUCCESS_ACTION"
    );

    // do some assertions on the successAction
  })
});
```

When this test runs, it breaks with the error message:

> Error { message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')" }

What this is telling me is that the call to `jwtDecode` in the actual saga code is running with the string 'jwt', because that is what the payload is.  But that is not what I am trying to achieve - rather than actually passing the value to `jwtDecode` in the saga, I want jest to mock the return value of `jwtDecode(access_token)` using the value I specify in the test.

What am I doing wrong here?  Note this was working prior to upgrading to react 18 and removing all enzyme tests, but all that seems totally unrelated.